# How to display accumulated data in a line graph in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, syncfusion, linegraph

I'm sure this is a beginner question but somehow I fail to come up with a solution.

I've got a database table which is mapped to a MVVM which among other columns has two named 'DTS' and 'Movement'.

DTS                 Movement

01.01.2016 12:00    +6.5

02.01.2016 20:00    -4

03.01.2016 13:45    +4.4

04.01.2016 13:45    +10

... ...

Now I want to visualize this information in a Line graph with the Syncfusion WPF Library. The X Axis should be the 'DTS'-Column but the Y Axis should be the sum of the values of the movement column up to the DTS.

For example

X: 01.01.2016 12:00 Y: 6.5

X: 02.01.2016 20:00 Y: 2.5 (6.5 - 4)

X: 03.01.2016 13:45 Y: 6.9 (6.5 - 4 +4.4)

X: 04.01.2016 13:45 Y: 16.9 (6.5 - 4 + 4.4 + 10)

...

Is there's an elegant way to solve this?

Best Regards

Markus

Answer (score 0):

we can get the accumulated values by manipulating the movements and accumulated value which is bound to the y-axis value in syncfusion chart.

```
 private void CalculateYValue()
 {
    double temp = 0;
    for (int index=0;index<DataPoints.Count;index++)
    {
        temp += DataPoints[index].Movement;
        DataPoints[index].YValue += temp;
    }
}
```